# How to find co-ordinates of two intersecting features (circular arc and polyline) using arcobjects in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, geometry, polyline, intersect, arcobjects

I am new to arcobjects and i want to find the co-ordinates of the intersection points of a circular arc and a polyline. The problem is the my code is showing no points of intersection even though i know there is a point of intersection. The code is,

```
Dim circle1 As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ICircularArc = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.CircularArc()
circle1.PutCoordsByAngle(site, 0, 2 * PI, Dist1)
Dim obj1 As Object = Type.Missing
Dim segCollection1 As ISegmentCollection = TryCast(New Polylineclass(), ISegmentCollection)
segCollection1.AddSegment(DirectCast(circle1, ISegment), obj1, obj1)
Dim geom_circle1 As IGeometry = TryCast(segCollection1, IGeometry)
geom_circle1.SpatialReference = pGCS
Dim pGeom As IGeometry
        Dim pTopo As ITopologicalOperator3 = geom_circle1
        Dim pPoints As IPointCollection
If Not pTopo.IsSimple Then pTopo.Simplify()
        pGeom = pTopo.Intersect(pLine, esriGeometryDimension.esriGeometry0Dimension)
pPoints = pGeom
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks